# how to debug spring boot gradle projects faster in intellij idea?

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, gradle, spring-boot

When I develop spring boot gradle projects in intellij idea, if I want to change some code and restart the project, I have to click the **Make Project** menu item and this will trigger a gradle build.If the gradle deamon is dead, it will start first which is an upset process.

While in Spring Tool Suite, everything is so easy, just **Ctrl S** and STS will restart **immediately** witout the long gradle build. So is there any way to make intellij idea restart faster?

I know if the gradle deamon is alive, gradle build in intellij idea is not very slow and is acceptable. But on my computer, the deamon can usually live for only several minites. When I change some codes and want to see the effects, the deamon died. I have to start the deamon every time! Is there any other ways to make the deamon live longer?

Thanks a lot if there is any useful tips!

Comment: You might see if this helps. It's a bit dated, but pretty sure it still applies: http://www.greggbolinger.com/spring-boot-live-reload-with-gradle-and-intellij-15/

Comment: Answered [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000129204-restart-not-convenient-in-spring-boot-gradle-projects).

Comment: Thank you for help, both @Gregg and CrazyCoder . These are good ideas, I will have a try.

Comment: Use integration tests instead of full project debugging and if the project is so big consider to split. Microservice approach is good for big project and also there is a commercial product called JRebel for this purpose. But I prefer integration tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, thanks to @Gregg and @CrazyCoder 's comment, I found some useful links:

[Developing/Debugging a Gradle-built Spring Boot app in IntelliJ IDEA](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000033250-Developing-Debugging-a-Gradle-built-Spring-Boot-app-in-IntelliJ-IDEA?input_string=spring%20boot%20gradle)

I accidently enable the delegate to gradle option in idea, which will trigger gradle build instead of idea's build, which is faster than gradle's. So disable the *delegate to gradle option* is a choice.

From another post, I get some idea to use the continuous build in gradle: open a terminal and run `gradle assemble --continuous`, when files are changed(for example save files or defocus window), gradle will compiles files automatically. Then run the spring boot app use `gradle bootRun` or from the tasks in idea, everything is ok. But this way will start two gradle so ram usages are larger.

**Update:**

I found another way to automatically compile. Fisrt, enable *build project automatically* option, then use `ctrl shift a` and input `registry` to open a dialog, and then enable *compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running* opiton. Finally, project will compile automatically and spring boot will also restart automatically.